# Lightning Network Unidirectional Transaction

Tags: lightning-network

In Lightning Network is it possible to setup a channel to make payment in on direction only.  For example Bob is buying Donut from Alice every day.  So Bob put in 0.001 BTC into the channel and pay Alice 0.0001 every day for the next 6 days.  My Question is does Alice need to place 0.001 BTC into the channel?.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All channels on the lightning network are bidirectional, even if they are only used in one direction.  However, this does not mean that both parties contribute to the funding transaction.  In fact, in the current spec only a single party contributes to the funding transaction.

That said, your scenario is not a good use case for its own channel.  The overhead of a channel for the purpose of paying for a weeks worth of coffee if probably not worth it.  Most likely you'd simply route the payments over an existing channel and through other hubs and channels.